# How to sort file with a composite key based on range()

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort file with a composite key. I am using an `itemgetter()` object with the `range()` function to sort on several columns, selected from a start point to an end point. Below is my code:

```
start1 = 2
end1 = 4
sort_src = sorted(file_name, key=itemgetter(range(int(start1), int(end1))))
```

This raises an exception:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Answer (score 2):

`itemgetter()` takes integers as arguments, not a `range()` object. Use `*` to have Python expand the integers the `range()` produces to separate arguments:

```
itemgetter(*range(start1, end1))
```

Take into account that the `end1` value is not going to be included; your range will select items with indices `2` and `3`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> row = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
>>> itemgetter(*range(2, 4))(row)
('baz', 'spam')
```